# Why JavaFX dosn't support .wav format?

Tags: java, swing, format, javafx, wav

1) Does JavaFX supports .wav format?
(Not clear from [Oracle's page](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) page)

2) If no, why so?

Swing is re-placement for AWT, and JavaFX for Swing, also
we say it's easy to play `.wav` file format in Java, then why  `Media` and `MediaPlayer` class of JavaFX doesn't support `.wav` format?  Any problems?

#### UPDATE

It gives me error when I try to play .wav files

**UPDATE2 :**

SSCCE:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.media.*;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javax.swing.*;

 /** Example of playing all mp3 audio files in a given directory 
 * using a JavaFX MediaView launched from Swing 
 */
public class NewFXMain {
private static void initAndShowGUI() {
// This method is invoked on Swing thread
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FX");
final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
frame.add(fxPanel);
frame.setBounds(200, 100, 800, 250);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);

Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    initFX(fxPanel);        
  }
 });
 }

 private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
// This method is invoked on JavaFX thread
Scene scene = new SceneGenerator().createScene();
fxPanel.setScene(scene);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    initAndShowGUI();
  }
 });
 }
 }

 class SceneGenerator {    
 final Label currentlyPlaying = new Label();
 final ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar();
 private ChangeListener<Duration> progressChangeListener;

 public Scene createScene() {
final StackPane layout = new StackPane();

 // determine the source directory for the playlist
final File dir = new File("e:\\");
if (!dir.exists() || !dir.isDirectory()) {
  System.out.println("Cannot find video source directory: " + dir);
  Platform.exit();
  return null;
}

// create some media players.
final List<MediaPlayer> players = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
for (String file : dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
  @Override public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.endsWith(".wav");
  }
})) players.add(createPlayer("file:///" + (dir + "\\" + file).replace("\\", "/").replaceAll(" ", "%20")));
 if (players.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println("No audio found in " + dir);
  Platform.exit();
  return null;
}    

// create a view to show the mediaplayers.
final MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(players.get(0));
final Button skip = new Button("Skip");
final Button play = new Button("Pause");

// play each audio file in turn.
for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
  final MediaPlayer player     = players.get(i);
  final MediaPlayer nextPlayer = players.get((i + 1) % players.size());
  player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
      player.currentTimeProperty().removeListener(progressChangeListener);
      mediaView.setMediaPlayer(nextPlayer);
      nextPlayer.play();
    }
  });
  }

// allow the user to skip a track.
skip.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  @Override public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    final MediaPlayer curPlayer = mediaView.getMediaPlayer();
    MediaPlayer nextPlayer = players.get((players.indexOf(curPlayer) + 1) %       players.size());
    mediaView.setMediaPlayer(nextPlayer);
    curPlayer.currentTimeProperty().removeListener(progressChangeListener);
    curPlayer.stop();
    nextPlayer.play();
  }
   });

 // allow the user to play or pause a track.
 play.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  @Override public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if ("Pause".equals(play.getText())) {
      mediaView.getMediaPlayer().pause();
      play.setText("Play");
    } else {
      mediaView.getMediaPlayer().play();
      play.setText("Pause");
    }
  }
 });

 // display the name of the currently playing track.
 mediaView.mediaPlayerProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<MediaPlayer>() {
  @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends MediaPlayer> observableValue, MediaPlayer oldPlayer, MediaPlayer newPlayer) {
    setCurrentlyPlaying(newPlayer);
  }
 });

 // start playing the first track.
 mediaView.setMediaPlayer(players.get(0));
 mediaView.getMediaPlayer().play();
 setCurrentlyPlaying(mediaView.getMediaPlayer());


 Button invisiblePause = new Button("Pause");
 invisiblePause.setVisible(false);
 play.prefHeightProperty().bind(invisiblePause.heightProperty());
 play.prefWidthProperty().bind(invisiblePause.widthProperty());

 // layout the scene.
 layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-font-size: 20; -fx-padding: 20; -fx-alignment: center;");
 layout.getChildren().addAll(
  invisiblePause,
  VBoxBuilder.create().spacing(10).alignment(Pos.CENTER).children(
    currentlyPlaying,
    mediaView,
    HBoxBuilder.create().spacing(10).alignment(Pos.CENTER).children(skip, play, progress).build()
  ).build()
  );
 progress.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
 HBox.setHgrow(progress, Priority.ALWAYS);
 return new Scene(layout, 800, 600);
 }


 private void setCurrentlyPlaying(final MediaPlayer newPlayer) {
 progress.setProgress(0);
 progressChangeListener = new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
  @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observableValue, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) {
    progress.setProgress(1.0 * newPlayer.getCurrentTime().toMillis() / newPlayer.getTotalDuration().toMillis());
  }
  };
 newPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(progressChangeListener);

 String source = newPlayer.getMedia().getSource();
 source = source.substring(0, source.length() - ".mp4".length());
 source = source.substring(source.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).replaceAll("%20", " ");
 currentlyPlaying.setText("Now Playing: " + source);
 }

  /** @return a MediaPlayer for the given source which will report any errors it    encounters */
 private MediaPlayer createPlayer(String aMediaSrc) {
 System.out.println("Creating player for: " + aMediaSrc);
 final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(aMediaSrc));
 player.setOnError(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    System.out.println("Media error occurred: " + player.getError());
  }
 });
return player;
}
}
```

Exception:

```
     Exception in runnable
     MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : Compressed WAVE is not supported!
at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Unknown Source)
at SceneGenerator.createPlayer(NewFXMain.java:176)
at SceneGenerator.createScene(NewFXMain.java:74)
at NewFXMain.initFX(NewFXMain.java:39)
at NewFXMain.access$000(NewFXMain.java:20)
at NewFXMain$1.run(NewFXMain.java:32)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$3.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Try using an [`AudioClip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html) instead.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Unsupported file format for sure!

Comment: Please post some code we can test i.e [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with an url to small wav

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, i am familiar with Audio Clip class related to  AudioSystem? If yes, this question is w.r.t  Media and MediaPlayer classes of JavaFX

Comment: We are not clairvoyant. Show some code and the detailed error message.

Comment: Your `.wav` is compressed, see my update

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems clear enough to me - [Supported Media Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMediaTypes)

```
...
MP4 MPEG-4 Part 14  H.264/AVC   AAC video/mp4, audio/x-m4a, video/x-m4v .mp4, .m4a, .m4v
WAV Waveform Audio Format   N/A PCM audio/x-wav .wav
```

EDIT :
So the obvious answer (based on your edit) is that JavaFX doesn't support *compressed* wave formats.

> **WAV**: Most WAV files are uncompressed, but they can hold compressed
>   audio as well. JavaFX has no support for playing the compressed form
>   yet. So when incorporating WAV files, developers need to make sure
>   that the file format is WAV containing uncompressed PCM.
>
> [source](http://www.developer.com/java/web/javafx-2-vs.-html5-media-support-for-ria.html)